# How to solve "unable to find valid certification path to requested target" with a server public certificate signed by a public CA authority?

Tags: java, ssl, https

I have a web server that hosts a webaplication and rest APIs over HTTPS. There is a certificate for *.thedomain.com **signed by Symantech installed on the server**. "thedomain" is for the example purpose. It's not the actual domain.

I think there is no problem with the trust chain, because the certificate provided by the server is accepted with the default setup of any browser without doing anything.

Now I'm trying to create a client in Java for the rest API that's provided by this server.

The problem is that a `sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path` to requested target is thrown. If I understand this correctly, it means that the ca supported by the JDK don't offer a valid certification path that allows to properly authentify the server.

What would be a good solution to this error while still being able to authentify the server ?
How comes the web browser are able to authentify the server and not the JDK (7) ?

Comment: It works in a browser because the CA certificate is in the keyring of your browser and not in the one used by JDK.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Thanks. I didn't add anything manually to the keyring of the browser. Is there a way to tell Java to use a widely accepted list of trusted CA (like the ones accepted by the default setup on most browsers) ?

Comment: Try with `keytool -keystore cacerts -importcert -alias aliasOfTheCertificate -file FileNameOfTheCertificate.cer` from the command line. Note that many Linux distributions already ship a `ca-certs-java` package containing all trusted roots.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo That answers my questions and closes the debate for me. I would gladly accept it if rewritten as an aswer.

Comment: Great. Rewritten as answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works in a browser because the CA certificate is in the keyring of your browser and not in the one used by JDK.

Use `keytool` to add your CA certificate to the JDK keyring with:

```
keytool -keystore cacerts -importcert -alias aliasOfTheCertificate -file FileNameOfTheCertificate.cer
```

from the command line. Note that many Linux distributions already ship a ca-certs-java package containing all trusted roots, try to use that if possible.

Answer (score 1):

So, a couple of ideas here.

1.) Symantech seems to be fairly new and might not be in cacerts file you're using.  Have you tried the very latest version of the jdk/jre?

2.) I would recommend using the [InstallCert](http://miteff.com/install-cert) application to create a new cacerts file that will trust the certificate from your site.  You will need to point to the new cacerts file in your VM arguments with the -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore and -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword parameters.

Comment: thanks for these ideas, but 1/ Yes I'm using the last version of the JDK 2/ In this situation I prefered to use a local situation with a custom trust store in which I have installed the server's public certificate. I was a bit surprised that I had to do that because I expected that a trusted CA would be taken into account out of the box by Java

Comment: BTW, this response is meant to be informative and not augmentative.  The InstallCert application is quite neat.  It does exactly what you're asking for, it will take a copy of the base Java cacerts file, download the public certificate from a site you enter, and add it to the newly copied cacerts file.  Which is basically what you did, but you had direct access to the public certificate, which works as well, just a different way of accomplishing the same task.